# Robots.txt is shown with a strange link

Tags: robots.txt

I have generated my robots.txt file and the content looks as a below

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /portfolio/web-application-for-core
Disallow: /portfolio/amazon-fba
Disallow: /portfolio/automated-tracking-number
Disallow: /portfolio/update-quantity-on-amazon
Disallow: /portfolio/add-products-to-amazon
Disallow: /portfolio/application-to-set-discount
Disallow: /portfolio/download-ebay-orders
Disallow: /portfolio/create-and-add-new-listings
Disallow: /portfolio/sync-quantity-on-ebay
Disallow: /portfolio/automated-tracking-number
Disallow: /portfolio/application-which-connects
```

But when I access it via browser the output shows

```
sitemap: http://cdn.attracta.com/sitemap/1295818.xml.gz
```

Just wonder how the above text is interpreted as below link

Comment: 1) Does it contain the `sitemap` line in addition to your `User-agent`/`Disallow` lines, or instead of them? 2) Do you wonder what added the `sitemap` line, or do you wonder what it means?

Answer (score 0):

It means that all search engine bot would be skip the urls beginning with  `/portfolio/web-application-for-core` and others as mentioned in `disallow`. i.e. any url which begins with `/portfolio/web-application-for-core` would not be visited by the bots.

Suppose your site is **https://example.com**
now all your sites would be visited apart from the site mentioned in disallow. **https://example.com/portfolio/web-application-for-core** would be ignored.

You can read more about the [guideline from the official documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Well. From where comes the sitemap: http://cdn.attracta.com/sitemap/1295818.xml.gz

Comment: you need to host it. Check the link for details https://serverfault.com/questions/549332/how-to-set-robots-txt-globally-in-nginx-for-all-virtual-hosts

Comment: @RinsadAhmed If you are using nginx, could you post your nginx settings? Seems there is something wrong in the nginx or any other server settings

Comment: I am at Bluehost. Will, that adds any clue?

Comment: I have not worked with bluehost, but quick google gave me this. https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2306

Comment: @RinsadAhmed did it get solved?  I was trying you access https://www.attracta.com/robots.txt, not sure if it is correct link or not, but to me it seems right